# Show that the propositions r → s and ¬r ∨ s are equivalent

Tags: discrete-mathematics

The question given in my homework is:

Is r → s and ¬r ∨ s equivalent. - True or False

The answer is True, I can't see the logic in how these can even belong together?

Can anyone please clarify this for me?

Thank you

Comment: Could you provide some details of how you're approaching the problem.  What have you done?  How have you solve similar problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Proof by truth table is a viable strategy here -- identical propositions will always have the same truth tables in classical logic, and also propositions with the same truth tables are always identical.

If you fill out a truth table for both, you should see that they are the same. Writing a proof by truth table in your homework is rock solid in 99% of all problems.

Comment: Oh! So the question to be understood is whether the truth tables of both are the same?

Comment: @ABCCode yes, that is indeed one of many entirely equivalent ways of looking at it.

Comment: @Asmussen: An equivalent way of looking at equivalences? I think I need a break to think about that idea ...

Comment: @CarlHeckman Formal proofs of equivalence of two mathematical objects are mathematical objects too; and can thus be proven equivalent. Category theory is all about this.